# How to avoid card from splitting into multiple pages on print

Tags: javascript, css, printing, frontend, printing-web-page

How to avoid this issue, I want to avoid splitting the card into second pages. Thank you so much for your attention.

[image]

Comment: Can you update this question with some more code. then it would be easier for us to debugg it for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

if your pdf is generated from html, then you can use css control the page display.
try add line in every page tail

```
<div style="break-after: always;"></div>
```

after this line, content will split to next page.

read doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I already tried this, but this doesn't work for me,